# what is cloud-based relational database

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

Why Azure is called `cloud-based` database? What is `Cloud-based` database anyway?

Answer (score 7):

A cloud-based relational database (SQL Azure, with the Azure platform) is similar to a regular relational database such as SQL Server, except that you don't have to worry about licenses, installation, hardware upgrades, customizations, disk allocations (e.g. where to store your transaction logs), etc. The upside is that you can deploy a new database server in under a minute, add databases in under a minute, and simply work with your application without worrying about the underlying infrastructure.

SQL Azure also provides durable storage: All writes are replicated on at least three separate disk areas, so that you don't have the risk of data loss. You still need a backup plan, as a DELETE statement is instantly replicated as well, but you don't have to worry about disk failures.

An on-premises database server has more flexibility when it comes to overall disk size, CPU selection, etc. However, SQL Azure offers a high-performance, high-availability database 'as a service' for you to build an application upon.

Some of the other answers here are comparing SQL Azure with Azure Storage (a non-relational set of tables, blobs and queues). You can certainly look at those options, but your question was specific to relational databases in the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Azure is a cloud database because:

- it's offered on **pay-as-you-go** basis;
- you can **scale up DB size** if you need to;
- **data is replicated** between multiple servers;
- you **don't need to worry about backups, hardware management**, updates and maintenance - Microsoft will handle this.

More about [cloud computing](http://abdullin.com/cloud-computing/).

Answer (score 0):

In Azure you have the choice between

- A SQL Server database
- An Azure table which is a name value pair

see: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazure/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Cloud based would tend to mean the data is stored somewhere else ie a third party provider.
It seems there is a trend to go from the traditional relational database design (old school) or the new key/value databases. The first would be the older style and the 2nd the new style.

The following explains the differences.. 
http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2009/02/is-the-relational-database-doomedp2.php